# Asset Paths Broken After Upgrade to Rails 4

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I have upgraded from 3.2 to 4. But assets are broken.

I have been using "assets/img/work/1.jpg" but I can't access to them in this way now. I can only access with digest like "assets/img/work/1-90041f6a6f670bd667cbfb47a50b27d2.jpg" what should i do? Only way is using image_tag?

Is using erb in CSS and JS files cause performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way that assets works has changed in Rails 4 so that sprockets-rails only generates digested assets. See [Changes from Rails 3x](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#changes-from-rails-3x) for more details.

As commented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536141/1322410) answer, there is a rake task at https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-20535134 that may be helpful if you need to generate static assets.

I can't comment on performance issues with ERB in CSS and JavaScript. The [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) implies that using ERB in JS and CoffeeScript is the "Rails Way" of doing what you require. If you are using sass, you can use image-url instead of an ERB file.

Answer (score 1):

Append RAILS_ENV=production to rake assets:precompile will bring back the digest in CSS.