# rake assets:precompile:nodigest in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

In Rails 3 there was a rake assets:precompile:nodigest task which was compiling assets and writing them without the digest part in /public/assets directory. In Rails 4 this has been removed, and by default all assets are precompiled with digest only. For various reasons I need also non-digested version of some of the assets. Is there any easy way to enable back the old behavior?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The version of `sprockets-rails` used in Rails 4.0.0 no longer supports non-digest assets.

Per [sprocket-rails's Readme](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#changes-from-rails-3x):

> Only compiles digest filenames. Static non-digest assets should simply live in public

So any assets that need to be static can be manually put into your `public` folder. If you need to copy compiled assets such as SCSS files, etc., this rake task may help ([source](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-20535134)):

```
task non_digested: :environment do
  assets = Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/**/*'))
  regex = /(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}*\.{1}){1}/
  assets.each do |file|
    next if File.directory?(file) || file !~ regex

    source = file.split('/')
    source.push(source.pop.gsub(regex, '.'))

    non_digested = File.join(source)
    FileUtils.cp(file, non_digested)
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest to use the regex: /(?<!manifest)(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}\.{1}){1}/
I removed '\*' from your regex and added '(?<!manifest)' part which prevents 'manifest*.json' file from being copied. The issue with 'manifest*.json' file is that capistrano's 'deploy:assets:precompile' task fails if there is more than one such file.

Answer (score 8):

There is also a gem to do this for you: the somewhat provocatively named [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://rubygems.org/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets).

```
gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"
```

Comment: even after installing this gem I was getting digested assets.

Comment: set this config.assets.digest = false in development.rb file

Answer (score 4):

As the best answer suggested, I recommend go reading the issue first to fully understand the background story, if you're not in a hurry. I like this idea most, https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-24837265.

And below is my personal take, basically I took the code from the answer above. In my case I only have 2 files that I want to be non digested, widget.js and widget.css. So I **use sprockets method to find the digested files and then symlink it to public folder.**

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w[v1/widget.js v1/widget.css]

# lib/tasks/assets.rake
namespace :assets do
  desc 'symlink digested widget-xxx.js and widget-xxx.css to widget.js and widget.css'
  task symlink_widget: :environment do
    next if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?

    digested_files = []
    # e.g. /webapps/myapp/public/assets
    assets_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'public', Rails.configuration.assets.prefix)

    %w(v1/widget.js v1/widget.css).each do |asset|
      # e.g. 'v1/widget-b61b9eaaa5ef0d92bd537213138eb0c9.js'
      logical_path = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset).digest_path
      digested_files << File.join(assets_path, logical_path)
    end

    fingerprint_regex = /(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}*\.{1}){1}/
    digested_files.each do |file|
      next unless file =~ fingerprint_regex

      # remove fingerprint & '/assets' from file path
      non_digested = file.gsub(fingerprint_regex, '.')
                         .gsub(Rails.configuration.assets.prefix, '')

      puts "Symlinking #{file} to #{non_digested}"
      system "ln -nfs #{file} #{non_digested}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to let the Rails.configuration.assets.prefix things at the end of your task to make it work for me.

Comment: I didn't know about `Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset).digest_path`, that's what gets you what you need quickly, this is the right wayt o do it! Although there is I think a way to simplify the code even more, there's no need to strip the fingerprint regex, you already know what you want the original filename to be, the `v1/widget.js` you started with, no?

Comment: Oops, `Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset).digest_path` doesn't work in production, where `config.assets.compile == false`. But this does: `Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets[asset]` and produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

My enormous analysis of all the available options is here:

https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/

I decided to add a custom rake task, using custom configuration to determine certain assets to produce as non-digested versions, and using the Sprockets manifest to find the digested assets and copy them with non-digested names.

https://github.com/team-umlaut/umlaut/blob/5edcc609389edf833a79caa6f3ef92982312f0c5/lib/tasks/umlaut_asset_compile.rake

```
# Rails4 doesn't create un-fingerprinted assets anymore, but we
# need a couple for umlaut's API. Let's try to hook in and make
# symlinks. 
#
# list of what file(globs) need non-digest-named copies is kept in
#     Umlaut::Engine.config.non_digest_named_assets
# defined in lib/umlaut.rb, but app can modify it if desired. 

require 'umlaut'
require 'pathname'


# Every time assets:precompile is called, trigger umlaut:create_non_digest_assets afterwards. 
Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["umlaut:create_non_digest_assets"].invoke
end

namespace :umlaut do 

  # This seems to be basically how ordinary asset precompile
  # is logging, ugh. 
  logger = Logger.new($stderr)  

  # Based on suggestion at https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-20535134
  # but limited to files in umlaut's namespaced asset directories. 
  task :create_non_digest_assets => :"assets:environment"  do    
    manifest_path = Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/manifest-*.json')).first
    manifest_data = JSON.load(File.new(manifest_path))

    manifest_data["assets"].each do |logical_path, digested_path|
      logical_pathname = Pathname.new logical_path

      if Umlaut::Engine.config.non_digest_named_assets.any? {|testpath| logical_pathname.fnmatch?(testpath, File::FNM_PATHNAME) }
        full_digested_path    = File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets', digested_path)
        full_nondigested_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets', logical_path)

        logger.info "(Umlaut) Copying to #{full_nondigested_path}"

        # Use FileUtils.copy_file with true third argument to copy
        # file attributes (eg mtime) too, as opposed to FileUtils.cp
        # Making symlnks with FileUtils.ln_s would be another option, not
        # sure if it would have unexpected issues. 
        FileUtils.copy_file full_digested_path, full_nondigested_path, true      
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Dylan Markow, I follow his answer, but I found that there are several versions of an asset (e.g.  application-0a*.css, application-9c*.css, ...) when using Capistrano so that **latest one** should be non-digested.  Here the logic is:

```
namespace :my_app do
  task non_digested: :environment do
    assets = Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/**/*'))
    regex = /(?<!manifest)(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}\.{1}){1}/
    candidates = {}

    # gather files info
    assets.each do |file|
      next if File.directory?(file) || file !~ regex

      source = file.split('/')
      source.push(source.pop.gsub(regex, '.'))
      non_digested = File.join(source)
      file_mtime = File.stat(file).mtime
      c = candidates[non_digested]
      if c.blank? || file_mtime > c[:mtime]
        candidates[non_digested] = {orig: file, mtime: file_mtime}
      end
    end

    # genearate
    for non_digested, val in candidates do
      FileUtils.cp(val[:orig], non_digested)
    end
  end
end

Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['my_app:non_digested'].invoke
end
```

As wells as, I applied 907th's regex comment, and add hook let this task executes after precompile.

Comment: In Rails 4.2 my digest is 64 characters so the regular expression would be `regex = /(?<!manifest)(-{1}[a-z0-9]{64}\.{1}){1}/`

Answer (score 0):

Set this  property `config.assets.digest = false` in `development.rb' file