# Rails 4: Why are fonts not loading in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, font-face

I can't load fonts in my Rails 4 app in production, it works normally in development.

Assets are precompiled on the server while deploying.

I have my fonts in

`app/assets/fonts`

My app.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WalkwayBoldRegular';
    src: url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.svg#WalkwayBoldRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

In my production.rb I have:

```
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)\z/
    true
  end
}
```

Comment: Are you using Heroku?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04, not heroku

Comment: Okay I have an answer, but we've only used it with Heroku so please be nice if it's not right

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We had this problem last week - the problem is that your assets will be compiled to have MD5 hashes on them, whilst your standard CSS will still be looking for their "standard" names. This is a problem with images & fonts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'akagi';
    src: asset_url('fonts/akagi-th-webfont.eot');
    src: asset_url('fonts/akagi-th-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset_url('fonts/akagi-th-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         asset_url('fonts/akagi-th-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         asset_url('fonts/akagi-th-webfont.svg#akagithin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is an example of how you should use [scss](http://sass-lang.com/) files to load assets dynamically. These files are compiled (either before push or during init) into your .css files, all with their assets correctly synced.

We had a similar problem to you with Heroku, and managed to get it working by putting our files into /stylesheets/layout/fonts.css.scss and then calling

```
@import '/layout/fonts';
```

We also called our application.css -> application.css.scss to support the @import function

Comment: To my rescue again! I was really struggling with this, and none of the other answers seemed to work. I think the most important point here is adding `@import '/layout/fonts';`. Thanks for this!

Comment: In my case i have the @font-face in application.css itself and my font files are in /assets/fonts folder. So will be url remain the same ?

Comment: It depends on where the fonts files are stored. We have in /fonts/ folder -- if yours are different, it will be a different path relative to the `stylesheets` path

Comment: this article might be useful for some : http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: This solution really helped me getting the fonts displaying correctly in heroku. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a generic way how to troubleshoot this problem for any library.

## Reproduce error on local

1. Run rails server on production

   1. On terminal `rake assets:precompile`
   2. This on `config/environments/production.rb`

      ```
        # Rails 4 production
        # config.serve_static_files = true
        # Rails 5, Uncomment to run production on local
        # config.log_level = :debug
        config.public_file_server.enabled = true
      ```
   3. On terminal `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`
2. You should see error on web browser

## Override font family

1. `application.css` needs to be renamed to `application.scss` since `asset-url` will be used
2. Add fonts to precompile on file `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
   ```
3. Look for font face definition inside your CSS library and copy that to `application.scss`. It should be something like:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'my-library';
     src: url('../fonts/my-library.eot');
     src:
       url('../fonts/my-library.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/my-library.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/my-library.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/my-library.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/my-library.svg?#my-library') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
4. Change to:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'my-library';
     src: asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.eot');
     src:
       asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.woff2') format('woff2'),
       asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.ttf') format('truetype'),
       asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.woff') format('woff'),
       asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.svg?#my-library') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

## What changes were made

1. Use `asset-url` instead of `url`
2. Change `../fonts` or similar to a path that `asset-url` understands.

## What path to put on assets-url

To know which path `asset-url` understands, go to rails console and enter `Rails.application.assets.paths`. You will get something like:

```
[
  '/path/1',
  '/path/2',
  '/path/3',
]
```

If your fonts are on `/path/2/my-library/fonts/` then use
`asset-url('my-library/fonts/my-library.eot')`.

i.e. You remove the path that part that you found on `Rails.application.assets.paths`.

## Check you wrote the right path

On Rails console on development:

```
helper.asset_url('my-library/fonts/my-library.eot')
```

Should return:

```
"/assets/my-library/fonts/my-library-2517b97e2c0e1e6c8ceb9dd007015f897926bc504154137281eec4c1a9f9bdc9.eot"
```

Note the trailing `/assets/` and the digest in the last part.

Comment: Excellent advice, thanks. In my case, putting the fonts into `app/assets/fonts/` and then referencing just the font file name without directory as `src: font-url('fontname.eot')` worked better, but the `helper` on console is a nice trick.

Comment: @speedracr. It should be src: font_url('fontname.eot'). Also in rails console you can use helper.font_url('fontname.eot').

Answer (score 1):

**Works with Rails >= 5 && sprockets >= 4:**

`src: url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.eot');`

Works **only** in development because in development rails serves all `app/assets` folder directly without pre-compilation (but not in production that's why rails can't find the fonts), so you can access what's inside `app/assets` folder with just the url `url`.

In production you need the pre-compiled version of these files. Rails precompile these files to `public/assets`. To access these files, you need to
use sprockets helpers: `font-url` or the more generic helper `asset-url`.

```
src: font-url('Walkway_Bold-webfont.eot');
```

In addition, all folders under `app/assets` will be pre-compiled automatically, you don't need to add `fonts` folder to sprockets search path.

You can check search path with: `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in rails console.

Answer (score 0):

1:- Keep all your fonts on app/assets/fonts folder.

2:- After rake asset:precompile RAILS_ENV=production all your fonts will get precompiled to public/assets folder with a digest.

3:- Instead of using src: url('fontname.eot') use src: font_url('fontname.eot') in scss files.

Answer (score 0):

Rails come with a prebuild helper for this. You need to use asset-url() instead of using url().