# Rails 4 fonts not working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets, font-awesome, production

I am trying to use fonts Awesome on my Rails 4 application. The fonts works very well on Development, But on Production is not working.

Assets are precompiled on the server while deploying with capistrano.

All CSSs files, JS (at app/assets/* and vendor/assets/*) are working... only fonts are not.

If I run the application on my development machine as production, it works:

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Only when I send to my production host (VPS with Passenger+Ngnix), that the fonts dont works

what I have is:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)\z/
```

And...

```
# config/environments/production.rb
# ...
config.assets.compile = true
```

Ad finally:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets.css.erb

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot') %>?v=4.3.0");
    src: url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot') %>?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') %>?v=4.3.0") format('woff2'),
    url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff') %>?v=4.3.0") format('woff'),
    url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') %>?v=4.3.0") format('truetype'),
    url("<%= font_path('Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg') %>?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }
```

The fonts are located at: `vendor/assets/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-*`

What I dont understand is that on Development it works and I have another app on Heroku with the same configuration and the fonts works very well.

If I go to my server using SSH and run `ls my_app/public/assets`, I can see all my assets (css, javascripts and fons) pre-compiled.

What I am missing?

Comment: try `asset-path` instead of `font_path`.

Comment: using `asset-path` causes an error: `undefined local variable or method 'asset' for`

Comment: sry, typo, you should use underscore. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path

Comment: @rodic the problem is the same... on development machine works, on heroku, works but on my production server does not work. If I open the Chrome console I can see: "`GET https://mysite.co.ao/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0 404 (Not Found)`"

Comment: I tried also `asset_url` and the problem is the same. On dev machine (development and production environment) works, but at live machine does not works

Comment: I wrote a generic way to diagnose and solve this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40898227/1197775.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked..

The only one that works was move the folder "fonts" from `vendor/assets` to `app/assets`.

This don't make sense to me, as I know, third-party assets must go to `vendor/assets` folder.

But the third CSS and Javascript files, are located at `vendor/assets/*` and works fine. Only fonts files that wont work.