# How to setup assets pipeline in rails 5 to use a custom font?

Tags: css, fonts, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to use a custom font [Jameel Noori Nastaleeq](http://www.urdujahan.com/urdu-fonts/Jameel%20Noori%20Nastaleeq.zip) in a rails 5 app. I have never worked with assets pipeline in rails before. Here are some of the steps I have taken:

1. create `fonts` folder in `app/assets`, and place the extracted `ttf` font file in it
2. add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")` in `config/application.rb`
3. add the following in `app/assets/stylesheets/couplets.scss`:

   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
       src:asset-url('JameelNooriNastaleeq.ttf') format("truetype");
   }
   Although there is no error/warnings, the above steps have no effect. Am I missing something.

I have already seen similar questions [Custom Font not working in Rails Asset Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334157/custom-font-not-working-in-rails-asset-pipeline) [Integrating @font-face files into rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849840/integrating-font-face-files-into-rails-asset-pipeline)
but their answers were not helpful.

Complete code in my [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/poetry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had generated the resources using scaffold. Adding desired `font-family` in `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.scss` fixed the problem. I have updated the [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/poetry).

Comment: @Todd: add your own answer if you desire, but please don't vandalize this one