# Precompile and include fonts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

After following some of the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294150/how-to-use-fonts-in-rails-4), I am trying to precompile Twitter Bootstrap Glyphicon fonts. They are pretty much just like any other custom font.

Here is my css in `bootstrap.min.css.scss`

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
           src:url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
           src:url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
               url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
               url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),
               url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
               url(glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg')
}
```

Here is my code in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf)
```

My fonts are showing up in `public/assets` after running `rake assets:precompile`. They look like this:

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular-3c36a8aade6ab06e8a1af9ab88110382.woff
```

And finally, here is the JavaScript console output

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://dry-temple-2989.herokuapp.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the following approach to add fonts to Rails:

1). Add `.erb` extension to your `css` file.

```
bootstrap.min.css.scss.erb
```

2). Refactor `url` to fonts in this file.

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
           src:url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') %>');
           src:url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') + '?#iefix' %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') %>') format('woff2'),
               url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') %>') format('woff'),
               url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
               url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg') + '#glyphicons_halflingsregular' %>') format('svg')
}
```

3). Add `*= require bootstrap.min.css.scss.erb` to `application.css` file.

4). Create `fonts` folder in `app/assets` folder and move font files there.

5). Add these lines to `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

6). Add these lines to `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .woff2 .ttf )
```

Works well on Heroku and VPS/VDS.

Comment: For completeness sake, I also deleted `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf)` from `config/initializers/assets.rb` because I had added it.

Comment: I was able to follow the "recommended way" here: https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570 that allows me to skip the erb file and inline the font-face css in my application.scss.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to rails guides. You should use fonts in your css files in the following way:

```
url(font-path(glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff))
```

You forgot to use `font-path` in the `url` definition. You can find more on Rails Guides part 2.3.2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets