# Rails application not loading fonts

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

When I try to load custom fonts in my Rails app, they do not load on the page, and when I inspect them in the source, I get a 404 error. But I'm POSITIVE I've done everything correctly.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: local(Roboto Thin), url("/assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.eot");
    src: url("/assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff"), url("/assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

And my fonts are definitely in `/assets/fonts/`

Here's how my `application.css` is laid out:

```
*= require normalize.css
*= require_tree .
*= require materialize.css
```

Where `materialize.css` defines my font files

What else do I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use fonts in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294150/how-to-use-fonts-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [font_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-font_url) helper instead of static urls in your CSS.

Comment: I was also able to fix it by adding 'config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")' to my config/application.rb file, but I'm also using Rails 4, not 5.

Comment: That shouldn't really be necessary, using the font_url helper will keep caching working properly, etc.  I'd still recommend it.