# Rails Asset Pipeline Paths(fonts) which only request once js method called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Develop with rails and Vue.js.

Vue.js use ionicons, and the fonts assets request is send only when some method called, such as below:

```
vue_instance.$Message.error("some message");
```

In dev env, it work well. But in production, I got 404 error with the font files request.

If the fonts request is write in css file, I can precomplie them and change the reference tag to asset_path and it will work in production env.

But How about this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although ugly... https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761449/6946797
Just add one more css reference of those fonts. 
In my project, I add one more ionicons.min.css.